# Problem deployment Django Rest Framework app to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to deploy a simple app to Heroku, and recently started getting the following error:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Post-processing 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-es-bundle.js' failed!
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_33d50075/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_33d50075/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 134, in collect
remote:            raise processed
remote:        whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-es-bundle.js.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f4a4526efb0>.
remote:        The JS file 'drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-es-bundle.js' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-es-bundle.js.map
remote:        Please check the URL references in this JS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to boundless-ea.
remote:
```

I don't remember making changes which provoked this error.   I'm trying to dynamically generate API docs from my Django app on Heroku.

It says that I'm using this static files storage backend `whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage` but the one I have set in code is actually this one:  `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'`

How can I fix this to get my app deployed?

When I run collectstatic locally, it works fine
I'm using Django 4.0, and whitenoise 5.3.0. and here is my settings file:

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

import environ
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False),
    HEROKU=(bool, False)

)

environ.Env.read_env(BASE_DIR.joinpath('.env'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '.herokuapp.com',
]

# Superuser
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME = env('DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME')
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD = env('DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD')
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL = env('DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whitenoise',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'django_filters',
    'django_extensions',
    'corsheaders',

    'api',
    'enterprise_agreement',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db()
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),
]
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles'))
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,

    # 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    #     'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
    #     'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer',
    #     # Any other renders
    # ),

    # 'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    #     # If you use MultiPartFormParser or FormParser, we also have a camel case version
    #     'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser',
    #     'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser',
    #     'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
    #     # Any other parsers
    # ),

    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://dashboard.boundlessdigital.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]

if env('HEROKU'):
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: What creates `swagger-ui-es-bundle.js` and does that get committed to source control?